# OR matches with BSD sed

Tags: macos, sed

I'm trying to filter out the lines in a file that match the regular expression:

```
DROP (CONSTRAINT|INDEX)
```

With gnu sed, this works:

```
gsed -e '/DROP \(CONSTRAINT\|INDEX\)/d' < myfile.sql
```

However, that same command doesn't work with BSD sed (specifically, the version of sed that ships with Mac OS X 10.8.3). How would I do this with BSD sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### sed

```
sed '/DROP/ {/INDEX/d; /CONSTRAINT/d}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about alteration, but you can use a couple of lines in BSD Sed (I, too, am on Mac OS X 10.8.3,  so can vouch that this command will work on your platform):

```
sed '/DROP \(INDEX\)/d;/DROP \(CONSTRAINT\)/d'
```

To test, I created a plain text file:

```
DROP INDEX a;
DROP CONSTRAINT b;
CREATE TABLE foo;
```

Comment: Looks like it would work, but I actually want to do "DROP (CONSTRAINT|INDEX|SEQUENCE|TABLE|EXTENSION|DEFAULT)", and that would be very verbose using this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `grep` would be a better tool for this job:

```
grep -v -E 'DROP (CONSTRAINT|INDEX|SEQUENCE|TABLE|EXTENSION|DEFAULT)' file.txt
```

will print all lines that do not match. I'm not sure that the OSX version of `grep` supports `grep -E`, though - it might be called `egrep` instead. Either one of those works on Linux.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but I really just want to know if this sort of thing is possible with BSD sed.